# Given $ab+c$, $bc+a$, $ca+b$, find $(a - b)(b - c)(c - a)(a - 1)(b - 1)(c - 1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Three numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ satisfy $ab + c = 10$, $bc + a = 11$, $ca + b = 14$. Find the value of $(a - b)(b - c)(c - a)(a - 1)(b - 1)(c - 1)$.

How do I solve this problem? I have tried numerous algebraic equalities, but they don't seem to work out.

Answer (score 3):

Rearrange $$(a−b)(b−c)(c−a)(a−1)(b−1)(c−1)$$ to $$(a−b)(c−1) \cdot (b−c)(a−1) \cdot (c−a)(b−1)$$ (I just changed the order of the factors).

Expanding the first group, we get $$(a−b)(c−1)=ac - a - bc + b=(ac+b) - (bc+a)$$ We know what both $(ac+b)$ and $(bc+a)$ are, so substitute those values. We can work out the other two "groups" similarly, and multiply them.

Answer (score 0):

Equation 1 is $ab+c=10$, equation 2 is $bc+a=11$, and equation 3 is $ca+b=14.$

Subtract eq. 3 from eq. 2 and factor to obtain $(a-b)(c-1)=3.$

Subtract eq. 3 from eq. 1 and factor to obtain $(b-c)(a-1)=-4.$

Subtract eq. 2 from eq. 1 and factor to obtain $(c-a)(b-1)=-1.$

Multiply the 3 numbers above and you get 12.